# Permutation/Combination Question

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A three digit number is to be formed by using the digit from 1 to 9 without repetition, find the number of three digit numbers that can be formed if

the units digit is an odd number, the hundreds digit is an even number while there is no restriction on the tens digit.

my attempt :

$P(9,3) - P(5,3) = 504 - 60 = 444$

Whats the correct answer ? is my answer correct ?

Comment: What are $P ( 9, 3 )$ and $P ( 5, 3 )$?
Hint: In how many ways can you fill the hundreds digit? In how many ways can you fill the units digit? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We choose the hundreds-place digit and the ones-place digit first, since they each have restrictions, and since the numbers that are "good" for one are "bad" for the other.

For the first digit (the hundreds digit) there are $4$ four even numbers that work: $2, 4, 6, 8$.

And for the one's digit (right-most) there are $5$ odd digits between $1$ and $9$, including $9$, so $5$ choices.

Now: For the second digit, (the tens digit) there are $9-2=7$ "good" numbers to choose from, so $7$ choices. (We can't use the digits chosen for the first and last digit, otherwise there'd be repetition, so we have only 7 choices available.)

Multiplying (by the rule of the product) this gives us $$\;4\times 7\times 5\;=\;140$$ "good" three digit numbers ("good": meet the criteria).

Comment: actually is from 1 to 9 not 0 to 9

Comment: You're welcome, @matin!

Answer (score 0):

4×7×5 since you're not allowed repetition and 0 is not included.